# Why won't my custom Perl install into expected directory?

Tags: linux, perl, installation, centos

I followed the instructions in [this](http://www.popmartian.com/tipsntricks/2011/04/11/build-a-custom-perl-installation) tutorial to build a custom version of Perl.

I originally did step 8 as follows:

```
./Configure -d -Dprefix=/custom/perl
```

After I did that, I did `make`, `make test`, and `make install`.

Then I decided that I want Perl in /opt/perl instead, so I did `make clean` and repeated the process and did step 8 with the appropriate directory. Still installed into /custom. Then I deleted custom completely and re-installed with the appropriate directory in the `./Configure` step. Still installed into /custom.

What am I missing? I want Perl in /opt not /custom.

Comment: That would work. `make distclean` does indeed delete `config.sh` and `Policy.sh`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right usage for 5.16, as per its `INSTALL` file: "You can also specify any prefix location by adding "`-Dprefix='/some/dir'`" to `Configure`'s args."

So I suspect that `make clean` does not remove the files created by `Configure`. Try it from a fresh directory instead of a "cleaned" directory. Or at least try deleting `config.sh` and `Policy.sh`.

[Upd: It was pointed out that `make distclean` can be used to do this. Of course, so can `git clean -dfx` if you're installing from the repo instead of from the tarball. ]

Comment: By "fresh", ikegami means delete the whole build directory and extract a new one from your .zip/tarball ;)

Comment: @goldilocks, That's what fresh means, although I've added that I think all that's needed is to remove the two files created by `Configure`.

Comment: Looks like my `configure.sh` still had instances of `/custom` in it. Deleted it and Policy.sh and restarting the process. Looks like it's working... I'll let you know in a minute.

Comment: I don't know why command line args to `Configure` don't override previously picked settings, but I had a similar problem trying to build a threaded build (`-Dusethreads`) after building non-threaded one. You might want to checkout the excellent [`perlbrew`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlbrew) if you want to have multiple builds of Perl.

Comment: /opt/perl/bin/perl -e 'print "hello world\n";'
hello world

Answer (score 1):

The `-d` option to `./Configure` causes the build process to source your existing `config.sh` file. The `-Dprefix=...` option will override the `prefix` setting in your existing `config.sh`, but unfortunately it won't override a number of other options that could be set in `config.sh` based on an earlier setting for `prefix`.

In addition to `make clean`, you also need to `rm config.sh` in order to safely reuse a perl build directory.

If you intend to copy the settings from your build process to another machine, you'll also want to clean out `Policy.sh`.